# Laravel Social OAuth Authentication - Password?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel Socialite to register a user via an outside website. That works just fine, but I'm confused the best way to make sure the user is authenticated each time they come to my website.

Normally, a user will register with a username/email address and password. Then, we check the database against their inputted credentials and log that user in. But authenticating with an outside website, I don't have access to that user's password, just other credentials that are available (i.e. email address obtained from the 3rd party website).

So, if they register/login through an outside website, once the user is redirected back to my website, should I just authenticate like this? This is where I get confused because normally I include a 2nd key/value pair which is the password for the user.

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $user['email']))
{
   return redirect()->route('route');
}
```

UPDATE:

Shouldn't this simple Laravel authentication be sufficient? The 3rd party website I'm using to login handles the authentication workload. It seems that I'm just needing to authenticate through Laravel to be able to utilize the Auth facade for the current user.

Comment: are you using a service like firebase?

Comment: I am not. Just Laravel Socialite package for OAuth. Not needing anything other than simple authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this was simple. The 3rd party website handles their authentication and once the user is redirected back to my website, they're good to go. So, I just push a session cookie to them and they're all set.

```
Auth::login($user, true);
```